# How to cut a cake that was baked in a pie pan?

Tags: baking, cake, freezing, cutting

I'm trying to make layers with my ice-cream cake but I need it to be even and straight on the top and the sides, since there will be a significant cake dome. However, I do not have a proper cake pan. Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Are you baking a bottom and top cake layer in pie plates (glass or metal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the bottom layer, top down, on a plate. Add the ice cream, but do not spread it to the outside edge of the cake. Top with the second cake layer, pressing gently. Then, using a sharp knife, slice vertically completely around the edge, removing the sloped edges of the cake. Surround the outside edge with a wrap of parchment paper or foil. Chill. After the cake is firm, you can slice horizontally to level the mound at the top of the cake, if you wish, before removing the paper/foil cuff.

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely easiest to cut things baked in a pie tin after you've dumped them out upside down. you can place a cutting board on top of the pie tin, then flip them both over together and pull the pie tin off the top of your cake.